# A text editor for Linux that remembers open files

Tags: linux, editor

I'm looking for an editor that is more or less like Windows' `Notepad++` in that it:

- remembers open files **without manual session saving** when closing and starting the editor
- remembers cursor positions in all tabs
- has something like N++'s "Search in all open files"
- it is more "lightweight" than Atom

I've used `N++` under `wine` for some time, but it's not satisfactory solution.

I've tried lots of editors for Linux including `notepadqq`, but it's surprising that in this day and age there is no editor for Linux that would have *all* of this built-in.

For now I use Atom that at least remembers files and cursor positions, but it's kinda slow and consumes a bit too much memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Geany**](https://www.geany.org/) does this in its default settings:

1. It opens each file in a tab.
2. It automatically opens the files that were open.
3. It remembers the last cursor position for each automatically opened file.
4. It allows searching in all opened files (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and use the "In session" button).

Geany is free/libre software, available cross-platform (including for GNU/Linux), and gratis.

I don’t know Atom, but I think Geany is a lightweight editor. At least [its Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany) agrees: "Geany is a lightweight GUI text editor […]".

Comment: I used geany a while ago and it could not remember the open files back then, thank you.